# Event Handlers | Custom Event

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I've set "Play pre-recorded audio" on one page. After the playing audio has finished, I'm going to make Dialogflow CX go to the "End Session" page. How can I set an event handler to handle the playback finished event? Also, if I need to define a custom event, how can I define it to handle that event?

Thank you in advance for your help.